# Gmail is sending me extra messages with a notification of "554 554 delivery error"

Tags: gmail

Recently with each email message I receive at my Gmail account I receive a second message from Google with the following information:

> #### Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
>
> mailed-by: googlemail.com
>
> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
> exampleuser@yahoo.com
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
> Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain.
> We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error.
>
> The error that the other server returned was:
> 554 554 delivery error: dd
>
> Sorry your message to exampleuser@yahoo.com cannot be delivered.
> This account has been disabled or discontinued [#102]. -
> mta1192.mail.mud.yahoo.com (state 18).

I do not recall having opened an account with Yahoo! and would like to correct this situation.  What should or can I do about this?

Comment: In your gmail settings do you have any new forwarding rules that you didn't create?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you've got a rule in place that is forwarding all your mail to a yahoo address that doesn't exist.  Check the filters tab under the mail settings.

As Alex pointed out if you didn't create the filter, delete it and change your gMail password.

Comment: Also, if you find that filter in place and you are absolutely sure it was not set up by you, **change your password**.

Comment: @Alex, excellent point.